# How to override an inherited class property in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, oop, properties

In one file, I have a baseclass with a ID-property:

```
type
  TBase = class
  private  
    class function GetID(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; virtual;
    class procedure SetID(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); virtual;
  public  
    class property ID[ACombo: TCombo]: Integer read GetID write SetID;  
  end;
```

In a second file, I have another class, descending from TBase. By accident, or ignorance or what ever, a new property/field with the same name as an exsisting property/field was made.

```
type
  TSubBase = class(TBase)
  private  
    class function GetID(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; override;
    class procedure SetID(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); override;
  end;
```

And use these classes in next way:

```
  TBaseClass = class of TBase;

  function Base(): TBaseClass;

implementation

var
  BaseInstance: TBaseClass;

function Base(): TBaseClass;
begin
  if not Assigned(BaseInstance) then
  begin
     if SOME_PARAM then
      BaseInstance:= TBase
    else
      BaseInstance:= TSubBase;
  end;
  Result := BaseInstance;
end;
```

---

```
if Base.StationCode[cmbStation] = SOME_VALUE then
```

But I got the error while compiling:

```
[DCC Error] uMyFile.pas(69): E2355 Class property accessor must be a class field or class static method
```

---

---

I have been trying also with static keywords ... and based on advices from collegues below was found some workaround.

```
type
  TBase = class
  private  
    class function GetIDStatic(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; static;
    class procedure SetIDStatic(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); static;    
    class function GetID(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; virtual; abstract;
    class procedure SetID(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); virtual; abstract;
  public  
    class property ID[ACombo: TCombo]: Integer read GetIDStatic write SetIDStatic;  
  end;

  TSubBase = class(TBase)
  private  
    class function GetID(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; override;
    class procedure SetID(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); override;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class of TBase;

  function Base(): TBaseClass;

implementation

var
  BaseInstance: TBaseClass;

function Base(): TBaseClass;
begin
  if not Assigned(BaseInstance) then
  begin
     if SOME_PARAM then
      BaseInstance:= TBase
    else
      BaseInstance:= TSubBase;
  end;
  Result := BaseInstance;
end;

class function TBase.GetIDStatic(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; static;
begin
  Result := BaseInstance.GetID(ACombo);
  // Or maybe below ?
  // Result := Base().GetID(ACombo); 
end;

class procedure TBase.SetIDStatic(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); static;
begin
  BaseInstance.SetID(ACombo, AValue);
  // Or maybe below ?
  // Base().SetID(ACombo, AValue); 
end;
```

But in this last variant - implementation is ugly and I agree with David about leave "the dreams" about an approach with using class properties AND SIMPLY refactor as described below:

```
  class properties ID[ACombo: TCombo]: Integer ....
  =>> 
  class function GetID(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; virtual;
  class pocedure SetID(ACombo: TCombo; AValue: Integer); virtual;
```

**Thanks everyone for fun digging there!**

Comment: Yes, sure duplicates is no needed. I have modified example

Comment: So are you still struggling?

Comment: Thanks a lot David! Yes, I was found some workaround ... but it's tricky and not consist approach as for me

Comment: Do you understand yet that class properties are bound at compile time? It seems judging from the edits to the question, and your accept, that you've not quite grasped that yet. I'd like to help you but you seem hell bent on trying to make class properties do what they cannot. The code in your latest edit is quite appalling. And it can be trivially solved using virtual class methods. And then there's no hack, the code looks clean. No vile global variables. Could you tell me what part of my answer you don't understand?

Comment: David, I do understand about properties and I don't hell bent. I have only one limitation I can't refactor production code. I can't accept for myself such solution and must ask my tops about refactoring these classes anyway!

Comment: Which code can you not change? You appear to be changing all the code in the question. Simply replace `class property ID` with virtual class methods and the job is done. You honestly believe that this global variable is the right solution to the problem?

Comment: David, I meant I can't refactor production code in my application... What about example, sure I can change `class property ID` to `class function GetID(): Integer; virtual; abstract;`

Comment: Well, that would get it done then. That's what my answer says. You'd need to pass the `TCombo` parameter, and it's not obvious to me that it should be `abstract`. But you presumably know whether or not that is correct. Why can't you just do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells by itself: "Class property accessor must be ... class **static** method"

You told like you could compile `TBase` but the error popped when you added `TSubBase`.
But `TBase` should NOT be allowed to be compiled. If it was - then there is a bug in Delphi.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Methods#Class_Methods

> In the defining declaration of a class method, the identifier Self
>   represents the class where the method is called (which can be a
>   descendant of the class in which it is defined.) If the method is
>   called in the class C, then Self is of the type class of C. Thus you
>   cannot use Self to access instance fields, instance properties, and
>   normal (object) methods. You can use Self to call constructors and
>   other class methods, or to access class properties and class fields.

So we could think of some workaround, explicitly stating the class that we want to cqall the methods of. Something like that:

```
class function GetIDStatic(ACombo: TCombo): Integer; static;
var RealClass: TBaseClass;
begin
  RealClass := Self; /// will not compile !!!
  Result := RealClass.GetID(ACombo);
end;
```

But...

> Unlike ordinary class methods, class static methods have no Self parameter at all

So the static methods cannot know which class was called at call-site. And so they call exactly the body of the function, defined in their own class. In this place - that would be exactly an abstract function.

However there is an obvious workaround that would allow writing things like

```
if Base().n.StationCode[cmbStation] = SOME_VALUE then
```

However implementation would hardly be efficient, so hardly worth it.

Comment: That's a bogus argument. You can use that same argument to "prove" that normal instance properties cannot use virtual access methods.

Comment: I have modified the example

Comment: This is not correct.  Virtual class methods work just fine.  Otherwise, the VCL's streaming system would not exist; it relies heavily on virtual constructors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan normal methods are not designed to be used *without an instance* but class methods are.

Comment: @MasonWheeler again, constructors are called against the class (class-ref var), not against the instance. And the class-ref is EXACTLY the pointer to a VMT. So in that case above, `SetIDStatic` should take `Self` and determine its real type before calling the method...

Comment: Class methods are called on the metaclass. They do receive a Self. In that regard they are no different from instance methods. It's just that the Self is a class rather than an instance. Static class methods have no Self.

Comment: Follow the links in my answer, and reconsider the bit where you state "You just cannot have a virtual class method"

Comment: Your latest edit shows that you don't really understand any of this. Class properties are bound at **compile-time**. That's really the beginning and end of this question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Okay, that was not very important for reading the error, removed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan persist with what ? i removed what you asked to, didn't you refresh the page ? "Do you not see that class properties are bound at compile time?" this is kind of repeating the error message itself. I did it, then you did it again, then topic starter read it. So is there where everyone should be silenced ? Cannot one think about explaining what happening and why ? working around it ? Maybe with some slight changes in sources?

Comment: I missed the final paragraph. I just saw the code using Self from a static method. I think it's easy to misread the answer. Perhaps you should flag it more clearly that the code in your answer does not work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan less depressing now ?

Comment: The upvote came when the answer had a number of factual errors. It's better now, but still seems a little over complicated. But thanks for addressing the errors.

Comment: As I see we can try replace Self on BaseInstance. So, Result := BaseInstance.GetID(ACombo);

Comment: @Young How does that help? Class properties are bound at compile time.

Comment: @YoungMaster what is BaseInstance ? some instance specially crafted to re-gain VMT ? that looks like the workaround i mentioned.

Comment: I have tried the approach adviced by YoungMaster ... and it's work! But it seems as some hack :) Maybe it does best for me redesigned classes and avoid this trick.

Comment: Actualyl in my workarouns .n was class-virtual method that returns pre-created global instance of the class. Then the property was made formally usual instance-based property with class-virtual setter and getter. Just because `Base().n.StationCode[cmbStation]` is closer to original sources than @YoungMaster's

Answer (score 3):

The compiler says:

> Class property accessor must be a class field or class static method

This means that you are out of luck. Although it is possible to implement [virtual class methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Methods), they cannot be used as class property accessors.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Class_Properties) does call this out explicitly:

> Class properties can be accessed without an object reference. Class property accessors must themselves be declared as **class static** methods, or **class fields**.

From this we conclude that class properties are bound to their accessors at compile time and there are simply no tricks that can yield run time dynamic binding. You'll have to use class methods if you want polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: Updated example again. Please look modification with static

Comment: The answer is the same. Class properties cannot be bound dynamically. Read the documentation link that I quoted to convince yourself of that.